# Date_Add in Bigquery with string input :

Tags: google-bigquery, dateadd

I am trying to use string input to compare a date range with date_add but it is not working though.

1. select  CASE
         WHEN cast('2020-01-10' as date) > CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE) and cast('2020-01-10' as date)<= DATE_ADD(CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) THEN 1
         else 0 end val
2. select  CASE
         WHEN cast('2020-01-10' as date) > CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE) and cast('2020-01-10' as date)<= cast('2020-01-16' as date) THEN 1
         else 0 end val
3. select  CASE
         WHEN cast('2020-01-10' as date) BETWEEN CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE) and DATE_ADD(CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE), INTERVAL 7 DAY )   THEN 1
         else 0 end val

While query 1 returns true but other two returns false. Any suggestion how it will work with date_add?

Comment: I mean to say query 2 is returing true

Comment: your query is fine, please pay attention to the date cast('2020-01-10' as date), you are using 2020 not 2010.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have said, be clear on the dates you are using.

To ease the confusion (and to mirror how you might actually use your statements in real-life), consider 'parameterizing' your dates in a CTE/table.  This will make your evaluation statements easier to read and you only have to define the dates once.

```
with data as (
  select cast('2020-01-10' as date) as test_date,cast('2010-01-09' as date) as begin_date
)
select test_date between begin_date and date_add(test_date, interval 7 day) as is_in_inverval
from data
```

This also might be redundant as `test_date` will always be less than the result of `date_add()` if the interval is positive.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing you query, I realized that your issue it is related to the dates you provide in your *CASE WHEN* evaluation.

Before, I would like to point that if you need support regarding the ***DATE_ADD*** method, you can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_add) as well as other useful methods.

About your first query, I broke it down into two pieces:

**I)**

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CAST('2020-01-10' AS date) > CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE) then 'greater'
  ELSE
  'none of the options'
END
  val;
```

The output for this one was ***"greater"***, thus the condition was satisfied.

**II)**

```
SELECT
  CASE
     when CAST('2020-01-10' AS date)<= DATE_ADD(CAST('2010-01-09' AS DATE), INTERVAL 7 DAY ) THEN 'less or equal'
  ELSE
  'none of the options'
END
  val;
```

The output was ***"none of the options"*** because you are evaluating if '2020-01-10' is less or equal than '2010-01-09', which is not true.

The same issue was encountered in your third query, where you use the *[BETWEEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators)* method. In your *CASE WHEN* statement you evaluate whether '2020-01-10' is between '2010-01-09' and '2010-01-09', which is not. Therefore, it makes sense not returning true.

About you methods usage, you used them correctly, your issue was only this minor misstep I explained above.

As a bonus information: You do not need to use the *CAST()* function within you **DATE_ADD()** method because BigQuery supports literal coercion from ***STRING*** to ***DATE*** or ***TIMESTAMP***, it states that:

> Literal coercion is needed when the actual literal type is different
>   from the type expected by the function in question. For example, if
>   function func() takes a DATE argument, then the expression
>   func("2014-09-27") is valid because the STRING literal "2014-09-27" is
>   coerced to DATE.

You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules#literal_coercion).

I hope it helps.